# replace 'null' strings with NULL in sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I wanted to check my column. If there was a 'null' string, I wanted to replace it with a NULL value. This works but is there a better way to do it? Such that I don't have to repeat the same thing twice `JSON_DATA :"ContactPerson"::STRING`

```
SELECT 
  IFF(JSON_DATA :"ContactPerson"::STRING = 'null',NULL, JSON_DATA :"ContactPerson"::STRING) AS "ContactPerson",
  FROM TEST_TABLE
```

I want to use REPLACE or REGEX_REPLACE instead.

Comment: Seems a very reasonable approach to me. Not sure why repeating the column reference is considered less desirable.

Comment: I agree with JNevill. An "better" solution could be to hunt down the person who thought it was a good idea to use the text `'null'` as a value and make them fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [IS_NULL_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is_null_value.html) could be a bit shorter:

```
SELECT
  IFF(IS_NULL_VALUE(JSON_DATA:"ContactPerson"), NULL, 
       JSON_DATA :"ContactPerson"::STRING)
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

or [NULLIF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html):

> Returns NULL if expr1 is equal to expr2, otherwise returns expr1.

```
SELECT NULIF(JSON_DATA :"ContactPerson"::STRING, 'null')
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

---

Regarding comments:

> *Still, how would regex_replace be used? REGEXP_REPLACE(  ,  [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ] )what would the subject be here?*
>
> *REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_DATA :"Business_Type"::STRING, 'null', NULL) AS "BS2",but this would give me NULL if "null" doesn't exist in the original value*

[CREATE FUNCTION:](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-function.html#optional-parameters)

> CALLED ON NULL INPUT
>
> Specifies the behavior of the UDF when called with null inputs. **In contrast to system-defined functions, which always return null when any input is null,** UDFs can handle null inputs, returning non-null values even when an input is null

and [REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html#usage-notes) function has this behaviour described explicitly"

> If any of the arguments is a NULL, the result is also a NULL.

Comment: Still, how would regex_replace be used? ```REGEXP_REPLACE( <subject> , <pattern> [ , <replacement> , <position> , <occurrence> , <parameters> ] )```what would the subject be here?

Comment: @x89 First argument for REGEXP_REPLACE should be text so `JSON_DATA :"ContactPerson"::STRING`

Comment: ```REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_DATA :"Business_Type"::STRING, 'null', NULL) AS "BS2",```but this would give me NULL if "null" doesn't exist in the original value.

Comment: @x89 Please see my update why you cannot use REGEXP_REPLACE that way